# dijkstra_sp_directed not returning any result

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, dijkstra

I am trying to create a routing application with OSM data. What I am working with is an almost square area of about 30x30 kilometers, so nothing too big. 
But when I do something like

```
SELECT the_geom FROM dijkstra_sp_directed('roads_clip','6','2','true','true');
```

It does not select anything. Both the table and the source and target vertices exist, as well as a possible path between them. This code is a part of a larger block that is about to insert the selected path into a new table, here's what it looks like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS shortest_path_table;
CREATE TABLE shortest_path_table(gid int4) with oids;
SELECT AddGeometryColumn( 'shortest_path_table', 'the_geom', -1, 'MULTILINESTRING', 2 );
INSERT INTO shortest_path_table(the_geom) SELECT the_geom FROM dijkstra_sp_directed('roads_clip','6','2','true','true');
END TRANSACTION;
```

All I get after running this is an empty shortest_path_table.

I have already used this code before and every time (until now) it worked like a swiss watch, so this time the problem seems to be in the data. When I run

```
SELECT assign_vertex_id('roads_clip', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

I get a nice and useable network of vertices, but dijkstra_sp_directed does not return any result. When I modify the tolerance to 0,001 it can find a way. The problem is, that the vertex network is a mess (I need a lot more vertices) and the route pgRouting returns is an even bigger mess (see picture: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/89/pgrouting.png/ )

As you can see, not only the returned route (in purple) is a complete nonsense, but also many streets have no vertices assigned, and that is not very useful.

I also tried this: http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/howto/validation.html and the result, (if I set the tolerance in assign_vertex_id to 0,00001) is pretty much the same as the image displayed at the bottom of the page.

So I know something is wrong with the data, the question is: What it is? And how can I fix it?

Thanks for your help